# Jupyter Notebook Table Appearance changes?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I don't understand why Jupyter Notebook saves some tables stylized and some not.

For example, in Jupyter Notebook, the following table appears stylized:

```
df.groupby(['Gender','City'])['Income'].agg(['min','mean','max'])
```

but the following does not:

```
(df.loc[df['Survived'] == 1].groupby(['Sex','Pclass','Age','Fare','Embarked'])['Survived'].count().sort_values(ascending=False)) / total_survived
```

I tried using the style guides but it doesn't seem to make any difference. There is no style applied to the first code listed above, but it still seems to generate beautifully as a table.
Any thoughts? I could be missing something totally obvious, but I can't seem to figure it out with the research I've done.

*(Unfortunately I can't add images here so it's a bit of a shot in the dark to assume others will understand what I'm describing, but I've tried in multiple notebooks and experienced the same results.)*

Comment: One of them is a series, the other is a dataframe. Try added `.to_frame()`

Comment: And tagging on what Paul said & your question, it's not that 'Jupyter Notebook Table Appearance changes'. It's that those types of **Pandas** data have different representational handling inside Jupyter. You'd probably always have better research results if you include '**Pandas**' as a term in your research. Ideally it would be a topic tag here and at least be mentioned in the post, if not the title. You can always check what type of Python object something is by putting it inside the parentheses of `type()`.